# Where form to get Azure Storage Authorization: SharedKey?

Tags: azure

There is this page that describes how to connect to azure storage via rest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key

On the page there is code example that has the following line:

> Authorization: SharedKey
>   myaccount:ctzMq410TV3wS7upTBcunJTDLEJwMAZuFPfr0mrrA08=

I am looking in the Azure portal, in the storage settings.
The question is: Where from do I get the **ctzMq410TV3wS7upTBcunJTDLEJwMAZuFPfr0mrrA08**= key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the article, in the section titled "Constructing the signature string" the signature is constructed for the request, it's not a fixed string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-signature-string

Specifically for storage you should read this article about creating the signature:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth#creating-the-authorization-header

Comment: OP is asking about the account key, not how to construct the signature

Comment: If that is the case, then sorry for the confusion.  But based on the pattern the OP provided, that is the signature.  The Header format is Authorization="SharedKey <AccountName>:<Signature>"

Comment: Oh, you're right. Looks like they have confused the key with the signature string

Comment: you are killing me. isn't there a simple way to upload a file to storage via rest? I spent like 5 hours already looking for how to do it.

Comment: @user11658885, it's Microsoft that's killing you.  ;)  But if you want to make this easier, might I suggest using one of the prebuilt Azure SDKs in your language of choice.  Doing this on the "bare metal" REST interface is by far the most complex method.  Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/.  Quickstarts for .Net, Java, Python and Node.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @bryanlewis, you have to build that string by following the instructions in the documentation page. But if you want to know where to get the access key needed to build the string, it's under the Settings -> Access keys tab in the Portal.

[image]